# How to detect if using Android Browser or Android Native WebView Client

Tags: javascript, php, android, browser, webview

At first i will explain what i have, and then what i want to do. I've been searching a lot and you can think that this question already exists, but i think is a very specific case.

I have a web application, using a template system with php,jQuery,javascript, etc...
Now what i'm doing is developing a **mobile web** version, with specific templates for mobile devices. It works fine but the problem comes when I wanted to include the mobile web in **android native app**, inside a **WebView**.

I have enabled **javascript** and everything needed to make it work, in order to use scripts for calling my own Android functions. And it works great!

The problem is that when I access from any browser from outside the app, the mobile web and Android detects the device, but it says that the functions are not defined when I call functions android native app like this:

```
   <script>Android.showToast("Welcome");</script>
```

So the question is, how can i detect if i'm using a web browser or a native app?
Or otherwise, how can i avoid the web mobile getting down for that error?

Grettings!!And thx for your help!

Comment: If `Android` is your native bridge, just check whether it exists before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

via `PHP` you can check the `user-agent` that is trying to access your web page. you can test with  one of these.

```
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'your_android_app_package_name' ) {
   //...Inject your javascript code
```

}

```
if( strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'your_android_app_package_name/') !== false ){
   //...Inject your  javascript code.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me a lot when I was using components that had environment dependencies in javascript. The way I usually do it is overwrite the global object with a local object and empty functions. In your case, you could try adding something like this before all the other script tags:

```
window.Android = window.Android || {
    "showToast": function(){}
}
```